# In EXCEL trying to count rows that meet 3 criteria:

Tags: excel

seeking EXCEL function to count without resorting SS. I'll be pasting this function in the SS everyday using "dataload" - to look for rows that are started (date entered), not completed (no date), and > than 2 days (date started)
The 3 criteria are

```
1. if cell notblank - A1:A10 
2. if another cell isblank, B1:B10
3. if date in A1:A10 is older than 2 days from current
```

So, in the linked example - the result of the function should = 2
only counting the 2 rows shown in green. I added for problem solving only a "Count logic" & "Function comment" for explanation only
I've tried COUNTIFS to see of adjacent cell is blank, and with =TODAY-2 days
but I'm stumped - any help appreciated
[SS link - can't post images yet](http://imgur.com/xgd9FbP)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
=COUNTIFS(A1:A10,"<"&TODAY()-2,B1:B10,"")
```

Comment: marked accepted -** this is working great - I put this right at the top of the SS in a dashboard - thks again